# Why can´t our dog bark with a high pitch while holding a stick in her mouth?

Tags: dogs, anatomy

When I throw sticks with our dog (a Swiss Shepherd) she usually barks at me with a high pitch when I'm about to throw the stick. Sometimes she still has another stick in her mouth and in that case her barking is much lower concerning the pitch. Why is that?

Comment: And they send the question here!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that higher pitched barks often require a dog to open their mouths. Your dog's pitch is changing because she is unable to open her mouth while having a stick in it.